# Couldnt get users from sharepoint group via pnp js selective imports

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, pnp-js-core, pnpjs

I am using code from documentation, basically the following to get all users from SharePoint group through selective imports.

```
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp";
import "@pnp/sp/webs";
import "@pnp/sp/site-groups";

// get all users of group 
const users = await sp.web.siteGroups.getByName("GroupName").users();
```

But it doesn't work and throws the following exception:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'getByName' of undefined

It works correctly if I use `import {sp, SiteGroups } from "@pnp/sp/presets/all";`

Comment: Which version SP PnP JS are you using?

Comment: "@pnp/sp": "2.0.7",